# Segmentation Fault occurring within my shell implementation

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault

I am writing a shell in C to run on PuTTy. The shell should be able to take any common command "ls", "pwd", and potential arguments that follow for instance "ls -l", and I am being met with a segmentation fault. I am aware that a segmentation fault occurs when attempting to access memory that the program does not have access to. However, I am unsure where this occurring within the following code. The segmentation fault occurs upon entering commands of different numbers of arguments. For instance, the program is capable of taking "ls -l" and will work properly. However, if we go from entering "ls" and afterwards enter "ls -l" this will throw a segmentation fault. Put simply the segmentation fault occurs when entering commands that have a larger amount of arguments.

I have deeply analyzed the code a multitude of times to check my logic. Unfortunately, I am not seeing my error, and I am newer to C as a language in general. I believe the issue is occurring within the "tokenizer" function, but I may be completely wrong. Do I potentially need to free memory somewhere?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



//-----Intro function-----//
//This function grabs user
//input and returns it.
//Also prints the shell name

char* intro(){
  printf("TamuccShell>> ");
  char* userInput = NULL;
  static char dataStr[200]; 
  int i = 0;

  if(fgets(dataStr, 200, stdin)==NULL)   // The statement reads a line
  {
      printf("Error\n");
      return userInput;
  } 
  userInput = dataStr;
  

  return userInput;


}

//-----Tokenizer function-----//
//Variables:Char**, Char*, 
//toks is to hold arguments
//data holds user input data
//which are the commands

void tokenizer(char** toks, char* data){
  
  int i = 0;
  data[strlen(data) - 1] = '\0'; //  It replaces newline ch with null
  
  char* token = strtok(data, " "); // Returns first token with delimiter space
  
  // strcpy(command,token);// stores first token in this pointer to seperate our command from our arguments
  // Keep extracting tokens
  
  while (token != NULL) { 
    
    strcpy(toks[i],token);
  
    token = strtok(NULL, " "); 
    i+=1;
  } 
  toks[i] = (char *)0; 

}


int main(){
  char *tokens;//User given tokens fed into tokenizer functions
  
  //--------VARIABLES FOR EXECV FUNCTION-----------------//
  int pid;//process ID for child process
  int status;//status for child process, this will be an indicator for the parent process to continue
  char* folder;//Destination for command to execute 
  char* argv[10];// reservation for commands argv[0] will be the actual command argv[1] will be arguments ,argv[2] null for termination 
  folder = (char*)malloc(200);      // Allocate 20 character positions
  
  int i;//iterator used with for loop below.
  for(i =0; i< 10;i++){//allocating memory for each given argument
    argv[i] = (char*)malloc(50);
  }



  //-------VARIABLE for Tokenizer-------//
  char* userInput;// storage space for user input from intro function
  


  //----MAIN LOOP----//
  int active = 1;//used for while loop below this line
  while(active){
    
     //---FUNCTION CALLS---//
    userInput = intro();// Calling introduction program that grabs user input and displays the shell prompt
    tokenizer(argv,userInput); // fills command and argument with tokenized values
    
    
    
  
    if(strcmp(argv[0],"exit") == 0) // check for exit call
    {
      active = 0;
    }
    
    // else if(strcmp(argv[0],"hist") == 0){
    //   commandPrinter(prevComs);
  
    // }
    

    else{
      
     
      folder = strcpy(folder, "/bin/");    //Destination setup for bin, so we may access commands.
    
      folder = strcat(folder, argv[0]);     // Destination specification of command IE "ls"


      pid = fork();//creates child process
      if(pid == 0){// checks if this process is the child process
        execv(folder, argv); // call to the function in child process; execute command and exit from the child process
        
        printf("\nCommand Failed\n"); //only runs if execv call has failed.
        exit(0);
      }
      else{
        wait(&status);//makes parent process wait for the child process to
      }


    }
    
  

  }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: The code here has a mistake on line 27 `us*rInput` should likely be `userInput`. I bring this up because that means the code you posted doesn't compile which means it is not the code you are running

Comment: *"I have deeply analyzed the code a multitude of times to check my logic. "* - did that 'deep' analysis include running your code in a *debugger* ?

Comment: `toks[i] = (char *)0;` leaks one of the buffers you have allocated. So it isn't accessible in the future. You either can't use a null pointer as sentinel value(Which I believe is unacceptable in you situation), or need to keep a reference copy of argv around to restore your "working" copy of argv from between commands (and use to free the buffers when you are done with them). (You also never check that 'i' remains in bounds.)

Comment: At the end of `tokenizer`, you set the last element of the array `argv` to NULL, in order to satisfy the demands of `execv`. But `tokenizer` assumes it can use `strcpy` to place arguments into `argv`. Since the same `argv` array is reused for each new command, think about what happens when the second command has more arguments than the firs tone. What happens when it tries to fill in the second argument?

Comment: This isn't a compiler, it is a shell.

Comment: Really, you should rethink your memory allocation strategy. It's suboptimal to place a small arbitrary limit on the size of an argument (49 characters in your case) and much worse to do that *without ever checking that the limit is exceeded*. (The same goes for the arbitrary small limit on the argument count.) You can easily do better. Regardless of what you might have been told, the cost of doing a few new argument allocations is not going to be noticeable compared to cost of forking off a new command process.

Comment: Without a [mcve], your question is off-topic here. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, btw, `ls` is not a command built into the shell but a program. At least it is in most environments, but you have the choice to do it differently in your shell. Reinventing wheels can be an interesting experience.

Answer (score 0):

The program works if we do:

```
ls -l
```

But, it fails if we do:

```
ls
ls -l
```

In `main`, you are doing:

```
// allocating memory for each given argument
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    argv[i] = (char *) malloc(50);
}
```

Then, later, you are calling `tokenize` in a loop.

With `ls`, tokenize will set `toks[1]` to `NULL` (the last statement in `tokenize`).

This works but is wrong.

When we call it again with `ls -l`, `ls` goes to `toks[0]` but `-l` goes to `toks[1]`.

But, `toks[1]` was set to `NULL` on the *previous* call, so you are doing [effectively]:

```
strcpy(NULL,token);
```

Which causes a segfault.

To fix:

1. You don't really need to do the `malloc` calls in `main`. Remove the `for` loop.
2. In `tokenize`, change `strcpy(toks[i],token);` into `toks[i] = token;`
3. `tokenize` should check the number of tokens against the max limit of the token array.

---

Here's the refactored code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

//-----Intro function-----//
//This function grabs user
//input and returns it.
//Also prints the shell name

#if 1
#define ARGVMAX     10
#endif

char *
intro()
{
    printf("TamuccShell>> ");
    char *userInput = NULL;
    static char dataStr[200];
    int i = 0;

    if (fgets(dataStr, 200, stdin) == NULL) // The statement reads a line
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return userInput;
    }
    userInput = dataStr;

    return userInput;

}

//-----Tokenizer function-----//
//Variables:Char**, Char*,
//toks is to hold arguments
//data holds user input data
//which are the commands

int
tokenizer(char **toks, char *data)
{

    int i = 0;

    data[strlen(data) - 1] = '\0';      // It replaces newline ch with null

    char *token = strtok(data, " ");    // Returns first token with delimiter space

    // strcpy(command,token);// stores first token in this pointer to seperate our command from our arguments
    // Keep extracting tokens

#if 1
    int err = 0;
#endif

    while (token != NULL) {
// NOTE/FIX: check against limit of toks
#if 1
        if (i >= (ARGVMAX - 1)) {
            printf("too many tokens\n");
            err = 1;
            break;
        }
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: toks is a _pointer_ array
#if 0
        strcpy(toks[i], token);
#else
        toks[i] = token;
#endif

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i += 1;
    }

    toks[i] = (char *) 0;

#if 1
    return err;
#endif
}

int
main(void)
{
    char *tokens;                       // User given tokens fed into tokenizer functions

    // --------VARIABLES FOR EXECV FUNCTION-----------------//
    int pid;                            // process ID for child process
    int status;                         // status for child process, this will be an indicator for the parent process to continue
    char *folder;                       // Destination for command to execute
    // reservation for commands argv[0] will be the actual command argv[1] will
    // be arguments ,argv[2] null for termination
// NOTE/BUG: don't use hardwired "magic" numbers
#if 0
    char *argv[10];
#else
    char *argv[ARGVMAX];
#endif

    folder = (char *) malloc(200);      // Allocate 20 character positions

    int i;                              // iterator used with for loop below.

// NOTE/BUG: these can be blown away by tokenize
#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          // allocating memory for each given argument
        argv[i] = (char *) malloc(50);
    }
#endif

    // -------VARIABLE for Tokenizer-------//
    char *userInput;                    // storage space for user input from intro function

    // ----MAIN LOOP----//
    int active = 1;                     // used for while loop below this line

    while (active) {

        // ---FUNCTION CALLS---//
        userInput = intro();            // Calling introduction program that grabs user input and displays the shell prompt
// fills command and argument with tokenized values
#if 0
        tokenizer(argv, userInput);
#else
        // skip command if parsing error
        if (tokenizer(argv, userInput))
            continue;
#endif

        if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)   // check for exit call
        {
            active = 0;
        }

        // else if(strcmp(argv[0],"hist") == 0){
        // commandPrinter(prevComs);

        // }

        else {

            folder = strcpy(folder, "/bin/");   // Destination setup for bin, so we may access commands.

            folder = strcat(folder, argv[0]);   // Destination specification of command IE "ls"

            pid = fork();               // creates child process
            if (pid == 0) {             // checks if this process is the child process
                execv(folder, argv);    // call to the function in child process; execute command and exit from the child process

                printf("\nCommand Failed\n");   // only runs if execv call has failed.
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                wait(&status);          // makes parent process wait for the child process to
            }

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`